# Instasharp Tags.Recent returns 0 results

Tags: c#, instasharp

I am trying to get recent Instagram photos by specified hashtag using Instasharp library. My sample application looks like

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetInstagramPhotosAsync();
}

async void GetInstagramPhotosAsync()
{
    string clientId = "...";
    string clientSecret = "...";

    InstagramConfig config = new InstagramConfig(clientId, clientSecret);
    InstaSharp.Endpoints.Tags tags = new InstaSharp.Endpoints.Tags(config);
    var result = await tags.Recent("snow");
    MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(result.Data.Count)); // returns 0
}
```

But #snow has more than 31m photos! What am I doing wrong?

**UPD:**
Found an issue: everything works fine with clientId from Instasharp.Tests project distributed with Instasharp, but not with my clientId.

```
InstagramConfig config = new InstagramConfig();
config.ClientId = "clientId from Instasharp.Tests";
```

I've registred my app here: https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/, recieved a clientId and used it in my app. Maybe I have missed any vital step in registration? Should it work in sandbox mode?

Answer (score 0):

This working well from my side!

```
var clientID = "Myclient";
var clientSecret = "Mysecret";

InstaSharp.InstagramConfig config = new InstaSharp.InstagramConfig(clientID, clientSecret);

var tags = new InstaSharp.Endpoints.Tags(config);
var result = await tags.Recent("myTag");
foreach (InstaSharp.Models.Tag item in result.Data)
  {
      MessageBox.Show(...);
  }
```

I'm not sure, but may you make sure that "snow" case sensitive or not?

Comment: Updated the question.